# How to return result of a promise as a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, promise, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot for the discord platform that will search a SQL database and return the objects to the chat for people to see.

SQL uses promises and I have been unable to successfully turn the promise it is returning me into something I can return to the chat (a string or array).

This code queries the database:

```
function spell(name) {
var spellData = sql.get("SELECT * FROM spells WHERE LOWER(name) = '"+ name.toLowerCase() + "'");
spellData.then( value => {
    console.log(spellData)
    return spellData;
  });

}
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE spells (
    `name` VARCHAR(25),
    `casting_time` VARCHAR(95),
    `components` VARCHAR(215),
    `description` VARCHAR(3307),
    `duration` VARCHAR(52),
    `level` INT,
    `range` VARCHAR(28),
    `school` VARCHAR(13)
  );
```

I'm using node.js, sqlite, and discord.js.

Comment: For a start, use the `value` (the argument of `.then`), not the `Promise` itself

Comment: if you do that, @CertainPerformance - that would imply - `spellData.then( value => {
    return value;
  });` - which is redundant ... and still, `spell` won't return a thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return the `Promise` object to the caller, simply do:

```
function spell(name) {
    return sql.get("SELECT * FROM spells WHERE LOWER(name) = '" + name.toLowerCase() + "'")
}
```

Then, in your client:

```
spell('some_name').then(function(result) { console.log(result); })
```

Or, if you're into `await`ing:

```
let results = await spell('some_name')
console.log(results)
```

Don't know if you're making use of it or not but ["parameterized queries"](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet.html) will guard against SQL injection attacks. Your NPM package of choice should have an adequately managed implementation.

Comment: note, where you **call** `spell` you can either `await` it (in an `sync` function) or use `.then` to "access" the required value (oops, and now your edit basically states that exact thing so do I feel stupid :p )

Comment: Thanks for the help so much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be misunderstanding how promises work. Even after a promise resolves, it's still a promise object. So in your `then` callback, when you call `console.log(spellData)` you're just logging the promise object. The data you want is actually passed into the callback as `value`, so the working code would be

```
function spell(name) {
var spellData = sql.get("SELECT * FROM spells WHERE LOWER(name) = '"+ name.toLowerCase() + "'");
return spellData.then( value => {
    console.log(value) //log the returned value
    return value; // returning the value from a then function returns a new promise, so the spell function also returns a promise which you can handle similarly 
  });

}
```